# HTML Java parsing basic error?

Tags: java, html, html-parsing

Should be a relatively easy question, but as I am a newbie to java, I dont know the answer!

I have the following code:

```
String    FTSE    =            "http://www.bloomberg.com/quote/UKX:IND/members";
    doc = Jsoup.connect(FTSE).get();
    Elements trs = doc.select("tr:has(a[href='/quote/III:LN'])");
    Elements values = trs.select("td.value");

    link = values.get(0);
    System.out.println("text : " + link.text());
```

However, there are red squiggly lines in eclipse under the word 'link' in the penultimate and final line, and when I hover over it, it says this- link cannot be resolved to a variable.

How do I fix this?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `link` is not defined. Try:

```
YourClass link = (YourClass)values.get(0);
```

Instead of `YourClass` use the class that `values.get` returns.

Comment: Indeed, in Java the variable type should be declared before using it.

Comment: Results in a squiggly red line under the word text in the final line, with the error 'The method text() is undefined for the type Object'

Comment: See my edit. Use the returned type by values.get instead of Object. And add a casting if needed.

Comment: Sorry, as I said, i'm a Java newbie, and I dont quite follow. Could you give me the line of code which you mean?>

Comment: To see the type that `values.get` is returning, use `Object` instead of YourClass, put a breakpoint and debug to see what class is link.

Comment: What do you mean by the class that values.get returns?

Comment: `values.get`returns an object that has a class (String, Element, Integer, etc).

Comment: When I change the class to String, it has red squiggles under values.get(0) and text in the final line

Comment: Follow Nordenheim's advice. Read some basic tutorial on Java. You need it. We can't guess the type returned by the `values.get` call.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign `values.get(0)` to a variable `link`, which, as Eclipse thinks, was not defined or defined elsewhere. There are two problems and two possible solutions:

1. You never defined `link`. Define it and assign it the type of what `values.get` returns:

   `SomeType link = values.get(0);`
2. You defined `link` in another method. Since it's not in the same scope, you must define it for the global scope and then use it with `this` keyword:

   `this.link = values.get(0);`

Comment: What type should it be?

Comment: @BenHarvey According to the comments to another answer, I suggest you first start with Java basics, learning basic types. With time and experience you might want to return to this problem.

Comment: Perhaps an answer to my question would be more useful than your current comment